# CMake: Is it possible to get the destination install directory from command line?

Tags: linux, cmake, installation

Is it possible to get the destination install directory from command line? I want to be able to execute an install command like this:

> make install {some destination}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can affect this at CMake run time by setting the variable [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX).  e.g.

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: What if I have already specified the install path in `CMakeLists.txt` file, Like:  
`install(TARGETS ${PRODUCT} DESTINATION ${INSTDIR})`   
Will `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` overwrite it?

Comment: The install path you specify in `${INSTDIR}` is appended to the `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` if it specifies a relative path (doesn't start with a `/`).  This is usually the best option since the user can choose where to install to.  Check the [`install` documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:install) for fuller info on the `DESTINATION` arg.

Comment: What if `${INSTDIR}` is an absolute path? Does setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` at run-time have any effect?

Comment: No - it has no effect then.